# Negative numbers save as NULL in SQL Table

Tags: sql-server-2012, negative-number

I have different columns of data with positive and negative values, which I'm having problems saving to tables.

Specifically, when negative numbers close to zero (such as -0.52) are problematic.

I tried defining the data type as NUMERIC and I get error messages that it won't commit.

When I define data type as DECIMAL, it commits but stores the negative number as NULL.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  Was pasting from excel into SQL tables and needed to changed the formatting in excel.